# How to detect user selecting an entire row and distinguish if multiple rows are selected?

Tags: excel, vba, row, selection

How do I detect if the user selected an entire row on the worksheet?

I would like to return which row is selected so I can automate routines - such as copying the data associated with that row.

I want the automation to be applicable to any one row and not multiple rows.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the code of the worksheet you want it to run on.
You can also check the 'address' property to determine where the selection is.  This isn't a full answer, but it should get you started.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim bEntireRow As Boolean
With Target   
    bEntireRow = .Address = .EntireRow.Address
End With
    If bEntireRow = True Then
        MsgBox (Target.Rows.Count & " Rows Selected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Target is my passed parameter.  Selection is more global.  I didn't just hastily mash this code together with a few Google searches.  Not me...  never.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried out the code it works well for detecting the row(s) that the user is selecting. I will try to see how I can detect and filter out if multiple rows are selected.

Comment: @Tofulover - add an additional check `If Target.Rows.Count = 1`. And if you want to restrict to a specific row, e.g. row 2, add another: `And Target.Row = 2`

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys. The code works wonderfully!

Comment: FYI, if you're putting code in the comments, enclose it in ` (same key as the ~) to make it appear as code.  `While mind = blown DrinkCoffee()`